# DataTable.Rows.IndexOf throws System.IndexOutOfRangeException C#

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, indexof

I have a `DataTable`, called `table`.  I need to find the index of a `DataRow` stored in `table`.

```
DataRow[] user = table.Select("Username = '" + username + "'");
table.Rows.IndexOf(user[0]);
```

The first line works fine.  I know that it returns a valid `DataRow` since I use the `DataRow` elsewhere.  However, when I run `table.Rows.IndexOf(user[0]);`, it throws a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`, saying 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'  I do not understand why this throws an exception.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: in your table do you have a field that is "Username = xxxxxx"? That's what it is looking for.

Comment: There is a column called Username.

Comment: When you hover over user, in the first line, can you see {System.Data.DataRow[1]}? I ran your code by creating a dummy table and adding one row. It worked with no exception.

Comment: I think it's `user[0]` that's throwing the exception.  Your query must not be returning any results

Comment: @JFT it shows {System.Data.DataRow[0]}.

Comment: @ServerS then there's your answer.  your trying to select from an empty array. your select is not returning anything.

Comment: That's it then, you are not receiving any row from the first line, the count is 0. You might want to check for the count before performing the second line. cause when you use user[0], it is expecting the first row. I will put a sample code for you.

Answer (score 2):

@ServerS The problem is you are not receiving any row from the first line, the count is 0. You might want to check for the count before performing user[0]. Below is the sample code for you.I tried this and it works fine.

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Clear();
        table.Columns.Add("Username");
        table.Columns.Add("Marks");

        DataRow dataRow = table.NewRow();
        dataRow["Username"] = "xyz";
        dataRow["Marks"] = "500";
        table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        var username = "xyz";

        DataRow[] user = table.Select("Username = '" + username + "'");
        if(user.Length > 0 )
        table.Rows.IndexOf(user[0]);
```

Comment: @Rufus L I have added some comment. Thanks.